# blf is a module or a parameter?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, opengl

`blf` is a **module** or a **parameter**?

I have read the documentation of blender, and I do not understand well what **blf** matters, or if it is only a parameter.

I understand how to use it as a measure but I do not understand why it is `important blf` !!

[image: Font Drawing (blf)]

### Could you explain to me what you do in the end IMPORT BLF! ??

***taken from api 2.79 and does not exemplify anything with bge FYI***
[image: blender python api]

Comment: Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/145632/edit) question if you mean `blf` rather than `bfl`

Comment: thank you, sorry, i wrote in my movil but is no easy walk an write

Comment: since you are one of the oldest here, just clarify whether or not it is a module, whether or not it belongs to blender or is it python?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/#standalone-modules

Comment: thank you haha I stay the same with the doubt I do not know what your link means

Comment: @BlenderBlackened you asked him if it's a module and he send you a link that lists `blf` under "standalone **modules**". That means, "yes it's a module".

Comment: The stand-alone modules in link posted are all python modules.  They are distributed, and for usage, with blender.

Answer (score 1):

`blf` is a python module for font drawing in Blender as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/blf.html).

Comment: but i do not use blender 2.8, i use 2.79b

Comment: and I was reading the documentation of the api because I was trying to transcribe the file _init_ of blender that calls the libraries to generate the interface created by blender python

Comment: Yes and? The module still has the same purpose. The only real difference is that the 2.79 documentation uses an obsolete example for the Blender Game Engine. https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/blf.html?highlight=blf#module-blf

Comment: nothing to do with my question, it is not even bge the example of the apy I do not see that mentioned BGE

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/python/generic/blf_py_api.c

Comment: @BlenderBlackened Blender provides the python module as an API to access Blender specific functionality for drawing text.

Comment: @BlenderBlackened if that doesn't answer your question, please try to rephrase what exactly you'd like to know.